# I'm trying to use a subform/popup form to fill data in a subdatasheet in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

The situation is this: I'm building an MS Access database for use by my Population Health department to manage data for calls to people put on COVID-19 quarantine. During intake, they ask if there are any cohabitants in the home. On follow-up calls, they will then ask the status of the cohabitants.

I have a form built to capture all of the intake data (FullTable_frm), and an additional form called Cohabitants. Cohabitants is a subdatasheet within my main demographic table. I want to use the case number (CaseID) to cover both the main member of the household as well as any cohabitants. My goal is to use the Cohabitants form as a pop-up, where if a checkbox on FullTable_form is checked, it will open the popup where records can be entered for any cohabitants at the home.

Every way in which I've tried to do this, I receive the error, "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required..." I have a 1:many relationship between FullTable and Cohabitants table, and on the table view it shows Cohabitants as a subdatasheet, which I can directly enter data into.

Any ideas as to where I might be going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: it sounds like a problem with the relationship or in other words the primary and foreign keys.  I'll try to whip out an example database.  if you can provide some to receive the file I'll just send it as the question isn't well formed enough to answer

Answer (score 1):

This is just a walkthrough of quickly creating a simple working access database based on your example. The table structure is bad but without more details we cannot come up with something more appropriate so we mention it and move on.  First create your two tables:

[image]

Next go to databasetools-relationships.  fiddle around until you get something similar to the relationship above.  the key point is to have CaseID in the FullTable and link it to CaseID in the Cohabitants tables.  You do this by dragging Case ID from the Full Table to the Cohabitants table (picture of how the edit relationship pop up dialog should look)
[image]

when done close the relationships window and click on the cohabitants table.  then go to the top of the screen and click create then form.  (it is important to create the relationship and the cohabitants form before creating the fulltable form.)

[image]

The Cohabitants form is done.  Now click on the FullTable and repeat to get the fulltable form.
[image]

Note if you already already made the relationship and the cohabitants form Access automatically adds the cohabitants form as a subform so you are done!  Go ahead and play with the record selectors on the side of the full table form to see how to add data to the tables and scroll through that data.  If something went wrong make sure you made the relationship between FullTable and Cohabitants then you can add a cohabitants subform to the FullTable form by dragging the Cohabitants table onto the fulltable form  in design mode.

Note: here CaseID is both a primary key and autonumber so access fills it in behind the scenes every time the user adds data.  If you don't control CaseID it is necessary to be able to enter CaseID but If access is keeping track and Assigning CaseID just remove or make the CaseID read only on the forms.

P.S. if the subform isn't working open the FullTable form in design mode and click on the subform.  Make sure the Link Master Field and Link Child Field are set to CaseID.
[image]

Comment: I think it was a relationships issue. Ultimately, I reworked the form and have it working now. Thanks for the help!